# Don't understand this code principle

Tags: c++, stl

```
// set::insert (C++98)
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;
  std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator,bool> ret;

  // set some initial values:
  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i) myset.insert(i*10);    // set: 10 20 30 40 50

  ret = myset.insert(20);               // no new element inserted

  if (ret.second==false) it=ret.first;  // "it" now points to element 20

  myset.insert (it,25);                 // max efficiency inserting
  myset.insert (it,24);                 // max efficiency inserting
  myset.insert (it,26);                 // no max efficiency inserting

  int myints[]= {5,10,15};              // 10 already in set, not inserted
  myset.insert (myints,myints+3);

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

I see this code as example on cplusplus reference site. It says

```
myset.insert (it,25);                 // max efficiency inserting
myset.insert (it,24);                 // max efficiency inserting
```

this is max efficiency inserting but I don't get it. 
Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: Please let me give you a warning: **[cplusplus.com is heavily outdated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad).** Use cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @Manu343726: Outdated in what sense? It has C++11 features listed...

Comment: I'll look at both, cause I heard that looking only one side will make you blind :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` uses a balanced tree structure. When you call `insert`, you are allowed to provide a hint to the implementation - which it can use to speed up insertion.

Think of how general `insert` methods into a regular binary search tree work. You start at the root node, and you must progress down using the usual checks:

```
void insert(node* current, const T& value)
{
    if(node == nullptr) // Construct our new node here
    else if(value < node->current) insert(current->left, value);
    else if(value > node->current) insert(current->right, value);
}

void insert(const T& value)
{
    insert(root, value);
}
```

In a balanced tree, this must perform (on average) `O(log n)` comparisons to insert a given value.

However, suppose that, instead of starting at the root node, we give the implementation a starting node that is where the actual insert will happen. For example, in the above, we know that 24 and 25 will become children of the node containing `20`. Hence, if we start at that node, we don't need to do our `O(log n)` comparisons - we can simply insert our nodes straight away. This is what is meant by "maximum efficiency" insertion.

Comment: There's no "far closer" about it.  If the element should be inserted immediately before the hint, insertion is O(1).  Otherwise, O(lg n).

Answer (score 0):

Have you read notices?

> position
>   Hint for the position where the element can be inserted.
>   c++98
>   The function optimizes its insertion time if position points to the
>   element that will precede the inserted element.

it points to 20 and precedes 25.

Comment: The function optimizes if the inserted element will immediately precede the hint, not if the hint will precede the element.

Answer (score 0):

In general, `std::set` has to look up where it inserts; this
look up is O(lg n).  If you  provide a "hint" (the additional
iterator) where the insertion should take place, the 
implementation will first check if this hint is correct (which
can be done in O(1)), and if it is, insert there, thus skipping
the O(lg n) look up.  If the hint isn't correct, of course, it
then reverts to the insertion as if it hadn't gotten the hint.

There are two cases where you regularly use the hint: The first
is when you are inserting a sequence of already sorted data.  In
this case, the hint is the end iterator, since if the data is
already sorted, each new value will in fact be inserted at the
end.  The second is when copying into the set using an insertion
iterator.  In this case, the "hint" (which can be anything)
isn't only used for syntactical reasons: you can't use
a `back_insertion_iterator` or a `front_insertion_iterator`,
because `std::set` doesn't have `push_back` or `push_front`, and
the simple `insertion_iterator` requires an iterator to tell it
where to insert; this iterator will be passed to `insert`.